# my hook or my function wont run in the cronjob

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic, cron

i have made a cron job to run a function but the function wont run. i did run the code that is inside the function, outside to see if it works and it did, it just wont do nothing if inside the function.

my hook `add_action( 'Stock_Sync_Hook', 'Full_Stock_Sync' );`

and my function

```
 function Full_Stock_Sync() {

                    $MasterwayRequest = new MasterwayRequest($this->APIKey, $this->APISecret);
                    $CompanyCode = $this->CompanyCode;

                    $CodArmazem = get_option('wc_mw_warehouse');
                    $CodLocalizacao = get_option('wc_mw_location');

                    $Stocks = $MasterwayRequest->stock_sync($CompanyCode, $CodArmazem, $CodLocalizacao);

                    if ($Stocks) {

                        global $woocommerce;

                        foreach ( $Stocks as $Stock ) {
                            $StockDisponivel = $Stock['StockDisponivel'];
                            $CodProduto = $Stock['CodProduto'];
                            $ID = wc_get_product_id_by_sku($CodProduto);

                            if ($ID)
                            {
                                $Product = new WC_Product( $ID );
                                $NewStock = wc_update_product_stock( $Product, $StockDisponivel);
                                echo $NewStock;
                                unset($ID);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $Product = new WC_Product( $CodProduto );
                                $NewStock = wc_update_product_stock( $Product, $StockDisponivel);
                                echo $NewStock;
                            }

                            $Product = new WC_Product( $CodProduto );
                            $wc_sku = $Product->get_sku();

                            if($wc_sku){
                                $ID = wc_get_product_id_by_sku($wc_sku);
                                $Product = new WC_Product( $ID );
                                unset($wc_sku);
                            }
                            $NewStock = wc_update_product_stock( $Product, $StockDisponivel);
                            echo $NewStock;

                        }//#FOREACH

                    }//#IF STOCKS
                }//#StockSync
```

The cron job is active but the function wont run, ive tried to change the time to like 10 sec and still nothing. Any ideias why it wont run?

Comment: Are you using a WP cron job or a server cron? WP cron jobs only run if someone is actively using the site. Basic troubleshooting should help - set up a much simpler function, run it as a cron job, and once you get that up and running, build your more complex actual function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

Im developing a plugin for woocommerce, so i was adding my Function to my plugin page instead of my include of the functions. Just put it on the functions and it works.